# Disable resizing for QLineEdit with PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I have multiple user input fields on my GUI for entering floats.
The problem is QLineEdit brings up a cursor when you hover over the bottom of the QLineEdit box to allow you to drag and resize the box vertically.

[image: Cursor]
[image: Outcome]

I would like to disable this functionality but can not find anything in the documentation that works to do this.

Please see a snippet of my code below -

```
self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 120, 137, 291))
        self.splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter.setObjectName("splitter")

self.transportField = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.splitter)
    self.transportField.setAlignment(
        QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
    self.transportField.setObjectName("transportField")
    self.phoneInternetField = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.splitter)
    self.phoneInternetField.setAlignment(
        QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
    self.phoneInternetField.setObjectName("phoneInternetField")
    self.mobileField = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.splitter)
    self.mobileField.setAlignment(
        QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
    self.mobileField.setObjectName("mobileField")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, or if you need to see any more code, just let me know.

Comment: What kind of widget is `self.splitter`?

Comment: It's QtWidget.QSplitter, will add to my code above

Comment: QSplitter is designed specifically to be able to resize its children. If you want to prevent the children to be resized manually, you should use another container or use a layout manager like QVBoxLayout or QQformLayout.

Comment: I've just managed to do it as soon you mentioned about splitter @Heike I added into my code self.splitter.setDisabled(True) and now it no longer allows them to be resized. Thanks all

Comment: If you don't want to use that functionality, why did you put a QSplitter in the first place?!

Comment: I didn’t.... I used QtDesigner initially to set my buttons and labels up quickly. When I was copy and pasting my input fields, it seemed to put them in a group together and when I broke them out from the group I’m assuming it was still within the splitter.

Comment: Designer doesn't create widgets on its own. I suggest you to be more careful when creating layouts (that's the only way to create a QSplitter in Designer), always check the object inspector tree and then study the documentation of the classes you don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.splitter.setDisabled(True)
```

This worked. I was originally trying to disable the QLineEdit widgets but it was the splitter that needed to be set to disabled.